# Merge properties from mapping table to single class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a website that is using EF Core 3.1 to access its data.  The primary table it uses is [Story] Each user can store some metadata about each story [StoryUserMapping].  What I would like to do is when I read in a Story object, for EF to automatically load in the metadata (if it exists) for that story.

Classes:

```cs
public class Story
{
    [Key]
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    public long Words { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class StoryUserMapping
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    public bool ToRead { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public bool WontRead { get; set; }
    public bool NotInterested { get; set; }
    public byte Rating { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

StoryUserMapping has composite key ([UserId], [StoryId]).

What I would like to see is:

```cs
public class Story
{
    [Key]
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    public bool ToRead { get; set; } //From user mapping table for currently logged in user
    public bool Read { get; set; } //From user mapping table for currently logged in user
    public bool WontRead { get; set; } //From user mapping table for currently logged in user
    public bool NotInterested { get; set; } //From user mapping table for currently logged in user
    public byte Rating { get; set; } //From user mapping table for currently logged in user
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this in EF Core?  My current system is to load the StoryUserMapping object as a property of the Story object, then have Non-Mapped property accessors on the Story object that read into the StoryUserMapping object if it exists.  This generally feels like something EF probably handles more elegantly.

**Use Cases**

Setup:  I have 1 million stories, 1000 users, Worst-case scenario I have a StoryUserMapping for each: 1 billion records.

Use case 1: I want to see all of the stories that I (logged in user) have marked as "to read" with more than 100,000 words

Use case 2: I want to see all stories where I have NOT marked them NotInterested or WontRead

I am not concerned with querying multiple StoryUserMappings per story, e.g. I will not be asking the question: What stories have been marked as read by more than n users.  I would rather not restrict against this if that changes in future, but if I need to that would be fine.

Comment: The first question I would ask is _why_ do you need this data in the root `Story` object? Is the `Story` and its navigation property not sufficient? Are you returning this data out through an API? I would veer away from adding your aggregated properties with `[NotMapped]` attributes to the `Story` class as this indicates a clear code smell that you're shoehorning data across entity models when there's a better way in the first place.

Comment: I would agree that this is a code smell.  The main reason I want the properties in the Story object is for convenience.  I'm using those fields as filters on the cshtml page of a web app.  I would be happy to leave them in a sub-object if that works better.  More importantly, I can't just get a normal relation of Story to StoryUserMapping because I can't pass in the Current UserId (or I don't know how to)

Comment: In which case I would advise to look at using a view model/dto/aggregate object to transfer your view data. You don't want to be skewing your entities to fit how they will look in the view - your controller/service logic will need to map/massage the entity data to fit the output/view. Have a read into best practices when creating an MVC web app and how it's best to separate your concerns across "layers" of responsibility in the app :)

Comment: I have added some use cases to my original question.  The issue that I see with the suggested approach is, if I try to satisfy use case 1 I query all stories with > 100,000 words, get 1,000 records * n stories.  Then have to manually filter those down to stories that I have marked as "To Read".  This is a potentially huge amount of data transfer and will ultimately result in very few records.

Comment: Thanks for adding some use cases - certainly helps see what you're trying to achieve. My original comment about using an aggregated viewmodel/dto object still stands, though. You can leverage the power of EF/LINQ to query the right data using your existing model, and _then_ an aggregate object to map your results to, and display them. I'll add an answer shortly that should help you out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create yourself an aggregate view model object that you can use to display the data in your view, similar to what you've ended up with under the `Story` entity at the moment:

```
public class UserStoryViewModel
{
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    public bool ToRead { get; set; } 
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public bool WontRead { get; set; }
    public bool NotInterested { get; set; }
    public byte Rating { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This view model is concerned only about aggregating the data to display in the view. This way, you don't need to skew your existing entities to fit how you would display the data elsewhere.

Your database entity models should be as close to "dumb" objects as possible (apart from navigation properties) - they look very sensible as they are the moment.

In this case, remove the unnecessary `[NotMapped]` properties from your existing `Story` that you'd added previously.

In your controller/service, you can then query your data as per your use cases you mentioned. Once you've got the results of the query, you can *then* map your result(s) to your aggregate view model to use in the view.

Here's an example for the use case of getting all `Story`s for the current user:

```
public class UserStoryService
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserStoryService(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<UserStoryViewModel>> GetAllForUser(string currentUserId)
    {
        // at this point you're not executing any queries, you're just creating a query to execute later
        var allUserStoriesForUser = _dbContext.StoryUserMappings
            .Where(mapping => mapping.UserId == currentUserId)
            .Select(mapping => new
            { 
                story = _dbContext.Stories.Single(story => story.StoryId == mapping.StoryId),
                mapping
            })
            .Select(x => new UserStoryViewModel
            {
                // use the projected properties from previous to map to your UserStoryViewModel aggregate
                ...
            });

        // calling .ToList()/.ToListAsync() will then execute the query and return the results
        return allUserStoriesForUser.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

You can then create a similar method to get only the current user's `Story`s that aren't marked `NotInterested` or `WontRead`.

It's virtually the same as before, but with the filter in the `Where` to ensure you don't retrieve the ones that are `NotInterested` or `WontRead`:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<UserStoryViewModel>> GetForUserThatMightRead(string currentUserId)
{
    var storiesUserMightRead = _dbContext.StoryUserMappings
        .Where(mapping => mapping.UserId == currentUserId && !mapping.NotInterested && !mapping.WontRead)
        .Select(mapping => new
        { 
            story = _dbContext.Stories.Single(story => story.StoryId == mapping.StoryId),
            mapping
        })
        .Select(x => new UserStoryViewModel
        {
            // use the projected properties from previous to map to your UserStoryViewModel aggregate
            ...
        });

    return storiesUserMightRead.ToListAsync();
}
```

Then all you will need to do is to update your View's `@model` to use your new aggregate `UserStoryViewModel` instead of your entity.

It's always good practice to keep a good level of separation between what is "domain" or database code/entities from what will be used in your view.

I would recommend on having a good read up on this and keep practicing so you can get into the right habits and thinking as you go forward.

---

NOTE:

Whilst the above suggestions should work absolutely fine (I haven't tested locally, so you may need to improvise/fix, but you get the general gist) - I would also recommend a couple of other things to supplement the approach above.

I would look at introducing a navigation property on the `UserStoryMapping` entity (unless you already have this in; can't tell from your question's code). This will eliminate the step from above where we're `.Select`ing into an anonymous object and adding to the query to get the `Story`s from the database, by the mapping's `StoryId`. You'd be able to reference the stories belonging to the mapping simply by it being a child navigation property.

Then, you should also be able to look into some kind of mapping library, rather than mapping each individual property yourself for every call. Something like `AutoMapper` will do the trick (I'm sure other mappers are available). You could set up the mappings to do all the heavy lifting between your database entities and view models. There's a nifty `.ProjectTo<T>()` which will project your queried results to the desired type using those mappings you've specified.